# Post data to website with cookies and viewState

Tags: c#, http-post, viewstate

I want to post data to a website. I handle the cookies with this code :

```
CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
         request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
              request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);     HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

I handle viewstate value with this code:

```
var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
              doc.Load(resp.GetResponseStream());
              foreach (HtmlNode input in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//input"))
              {                   
               if (input.Attributes["value"] != null)
                  {
                  val = input.Attributes["value"].Value;
                   if (val.IndexOf("1")!=-1)
                      {
                         viewState = val;
                      }
                   }
              }
```

and finally I'm posting data with this code:

```
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                         cookies = response.Cookies;
                       response.Close();
                       string getUrl = "url";
                       string postData = String.Format(""+viewstate);
                       HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(getUrl);
                       getRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                       getRequest.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
```

My main problem is viewState because if I don't post viewstate it returns me the same page or  if I parse viewstate value before the posting data and post with data it returns me your session timed out. For example I'm able to login facebook but I could not post data to website which uses viewState. I couldn't figure out this situation. I think I have to parse viewstate in the same request with post but I know that webrequest can not be reused. Can you help me?

Comment: Can you share with link and what you want to do?

Comment: apps.db.ripe.net/syncupdates/simple-rpsl.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using CsQuery lib. It's helpful and easy to use. https://www.nuget.org/packages/CsQuery

Use some class like that:

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{
    public CookieContainer _cookies = new CookieContainer();

    public string Get(string URL)
    {
        return this.DownloadString(URL);
    }

    public WebClientEx()
    {
        this.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
    }

    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {

        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.Host = "apps.db.ripe.net";
        request.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0";
        request.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Proxy = new WebProxy();
        request.AutomaticDecompression = DecompressionMethods.GZip | DecompressionMethods.Deflate;
        request.CookieContainer = _cookies;
        request.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", "en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3");
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

        return request;
    }

    public string Post(string URL, NameValueCollection data)
    {
        return this.Encoding.GetString(this.UploadValues(URL, data));
    }
}
```

Setup the post parameters as you want.
Then just do:

```
        WebClientEx client = new WebClientEx();
        string Page = client.Get("https://apps.db.ripe.net/syncupdates/simple-rpsl.html"); //get some cookies and viewstate

        CQ dom = CQ.Create(Page);
        string viewstate = dom["input#javax\\.faces\\.ViewState"].Val(); //get viewstate

        NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection();
        data.Add("rpslBox:postRpsl", "rpslBox:postRpsl");
        data.Add("rpslBox:postRpsl:sourceRadioSelect", "RIPE_NCC");
        data.Add("rpslBox:postRpsl:rpslObject", "your some string"); //your string
        data.Add("rpslBox:postRpsl:update", "Update");
        data.Add("javax.faces.ViewState", viewstate);

        Page = client.Post("https://apps.db.ripe.net/syncupdates/simple-rpsl.html", data);
```

Comment: i get error : type or namespace  NameValueCollection could'nt be found
why?

Comment: Add proper using:    System.Collections.Specialized

Comment: thanks it worked great. I have one more question. I dont understand how it works. it make multiple request in one connection?

Comment: It's prety simple. First we create class WebClientEx. It has two methods Get and Post. Then we Get our page to parse viewstate value. After that when we have viewstate we can just send Post request to our url with post data that we want to send.

Comment: I couldnt run exe in different folder because program couldnt find csquery.dll . I how to determine the path for dll in my code ?

Comment: Yes, @user3297904 - you can also keep that ".dll" file in [GAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache)